# Compiling CoffeeScript with AngularJS without Yeoman

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I try to translate [a little app in AngularJS](https://github.com/Cilyan/online-ldap-password-changer/blob/master/static/js/app.js) from JavaScript to CoffeeScript as a practice to learn CoffeeScript.

the [script `appcoffee.coffee`](http://pastebin.com/iKSfVWbU) now starts with

```coffee
'use strict'

UsrAdmApp = angular.module 'UsrAdmApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']

UsrAdmApp.controller 'UsrAdmCtrl', class

    constructor: (@$scope, @$http, @$timeout) ->
        # Init scope
        # etc.
```

which I try to compile with a simple `coffee appcoffee.coffee` but it fails finding the `angular` module.

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../appcoffee.coffee:6:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../appcoffee.coffee:56:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I tried the `-r angular` option but then I get `Error: Cannot find module 'angular'`. I tried having the `angular.js` file in the same directory as the coffee file, I tried `-r angular.js` too, having `npm install angularjs` put a `node_modules` folder at the same level, but I don't get that script compiled...

I don't want to use yeoman or grunt at the moment, because I want to understand how the whole thing works on a small project first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the answer on another thread by user icktoofay:

> The options must go before the file, e.g.:
>
> ```
>  coffee -cw script.coffee
> ```
>
> Otherwise, it will try to run script.coffee right then and there as a Node.js script, passing it the options -c and -w. That's not what you want; if you want the CoffeeScript compiler to get the options, it's got to be before the file name.

In other words, without the '-c' option, coffee tries to compile and RUN the script, and your terminal doesn't know what angular is.

Comment: Perfect. It was maybe so obvious that I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks a lot, this works great.